# VS2012 C++ - Prevent Visual Studio from auto-adding includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include, std

Somewhere in my code, I use std::numeric_limits, but I did not `#include <limits>` (I did `#include <vector>`, not sure if this matters). This worked fine for me; apparently Visual Studio fixes my mistake for me during compilation. Then, someone else who was working on the same code (with a different IDE) encountered compiler errors because of the missing include. Is there any way to prevent Visual Studio from doing this, to prevent this from happening again?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt the compiler is doing it. It's more likely that the header `<vector>` is including the header `<limits>`, either directly or indirectly. Or it is just including a file which brings in `std::numeric_limits` (a file which would also be included by `<limits>`). Presumably it is doing this because it uses something from that header.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers?  The `<limits>` may be already in the precompiled header (used by another header file).

Comment: Would this behaviour be different for different compilers? If so, is there any way to detect when I'm using functions from indirectly referenced headers?

Comment: I am not using precompiled headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support its own needs, `<vector>` includes `<limits>` (possibly indirectly through other nested includes), so it is available after `<vector>` is included.  Open the `<vector>` header and take a look.

However in a different implementation, this may not be the case, so you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Is there any way in Visual Studio to check if code is using indirectly referenced functions?

Comment: @JordiVermeulen :  I doubt it; the pre-processor inserts the included content and the compiler itself sees a single translation unit with all the content.  It's not clever or pretty, it is very simple.  Static analysis tools can detect unnecessary header files, but I am not sure they will detect missing direct includes if they are included indirectly - how would it know that it was not intentional? For example it is normal to include "windows.h" to use the Win API, but much of it is defined in deliberately nested includes (windef.h for example - it would be unusual to include that directly).

Comment: I see your point, it would indeed be difficult to differentiate.